# bootstrap modal click event destroyed after modal opens

Tags: jquery, events, twitter-bootstrap-3, click, bootstrap-modal

I use a modal called #mainModal in my HTML footer :

```
<div class="modal fade draggable-modal ui-draggable" id="mainModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-login" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

After that, in all my pages I open the same modal with different contents when needed with links like this :

```
<a href="/m/invoices/pay/313" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mainModal" class="btn btn-sm blue-madison tooltips"><i class="fa fa-money"></i></a>
```

When I click on my link, the first time, it opens the modal, **but right after modal opens, the "click" event is destroyed !? So, if I click same link or any other one (after modal is closed of course) it opens content in page (no more in modal).**

I have no error in my js console.

To reset modal content every time I hide it, I use this :

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
    $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
});
```

I think the problem is not in this portion of code.

Can someone help me ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in modal content script `document.off().on(...)` **was resetting all my click events on all the website**.

Sorry, my fault.